# Where to write the code for drawing square in UITableViewCell in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have the following code to draw a square outline with the following code.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 00.0, 50, 50));
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context));
```

I want to draw this square into UITableViewCell. So where should I write the cocde to draw a square in that cell.
I want to draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this code to cellForRowAtIndexPath method for table

i have written following code to add two label in my tablecell.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellId=@"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

   if(cell==nil)
   {
       cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
   }

   // you can put down you logic of customizing your cell here.
   //for example see mine code.

   CGRect frm1=CGRectMake(10,10,290,25);
   UILabel *lbTmp;
   lbTmp=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: frm1];
   lblTmp.text=@"something something"
   cell.contentView addSubview:lb1Tmp];
   [lblTmp release];
   return cell;
}
```